# custom action button in android keyboard

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I am trying to get a custom action on ENTER to work. Here's my xml for the EditText

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editor"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:imeActionId="@+id/submit_action"
    android:imeActionLabel="Submit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="15dp" />
```

However when I try to catch that action, I see that the action id is 5 instead of whatever is in submit_action

```
mNameEditor.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), Integer.toString(actionId) ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (event != null && event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            return false;
        } else if(actionId == R.id.submit_action){
            //do something
        }
        return true;
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method:

```
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);

            return true;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

In this example I have tried to close the IME but you can do whatever you want when ENTER key pressed.Hope it helps.